# How to deploy spring boot war application along with MySql database in a docker container

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, kitematic

I am trying to deploy my **WAR** **spring boot application** in a Docker container along with the **MySql database**.

I have a separate dockerfile for my spring boot application and a separate dockerfile for MySql. MySql and spring boot application are in separate containers.

When I am trying link the containers and run it shows an exception like `mysql.jdbc.exception.CommunicationsException`.

```
FROM tomcat:8.0.51-jre8-alpine

COPY demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/service.war

CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

**This is my Dockerfile for Spring boot application**

```
 FROM mysql:8

 EXPOSE 3306

 ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD root

 ENV MYSQL_DATABASE testDB[This the screen shot of the error][1]
```

**This is my Dockerfile for Mysql**

I am using this command to link the containers.
**`docker run -t --name springservices --link mysql-docker-container:mysql -p 8081:8080 services`**

**This error shows in Kitematic GUI container logs**

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:157) [spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) [spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) [spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:319) [spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356) [spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:73) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:142) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:113) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$85fd6b3c.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$6(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$85fd6b3c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$def4ab26.invoke(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) [spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) [spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$85fd6b3c.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) [spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
```

Comment: spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql:/mysql-docker-container:3306/testDB?useSSL=false my datasource URL